# Passing arguments to the function (Python, OOP, functions)

Tags: python, function, oop

So here we are passing 2 arguments to the function: 1) a just created object from the class (*counter*) and 2) a number (**0**).

```
def increment(c, num):
    c.count += 1
    num += 1



class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
 
 
counter = Counter()
number = 0
 
for i in range(0, 100):
    increment(counter, number)
 
print(
    "counter is "
    + str(counter.count)
    + ", number of times is "
    + str(number)
)
```

The result of the code is the following:

```
# counter is 100, number of times is 0
```

Why the 'number' variable does not increase, if the function clearly says:

```
num += 1
```

???

Comment: `num += 1` is equivalent to `num = num + 1` which just creates a new int with value `num+1` assigned to `num` without modifying the original value of `num`

Answer (score 2):

Every time the function is called the value is assigned to a new variable called `num`. I will not modify the variable.

So,
You have to return the value of `number` from the increment function and assign it to the number variable.

```
def increment(c, num):
    c.count += 1
    return num+1



class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
 
 
counter = Counter()
number = 0
 
for i in range(0, 100):
    number = increment(counter, number)
 
print(
    "counter is "
    + str(counter.count)
    + ", number of times is "
    + str(number)
)
```

Output

```
counter is 100, number of times is 100
```

The best way is to add increment function in the Counter class. But If you want to do this with function this way works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Python passes parameters by object reference, which results basically in having references to mutable types and values for immutable types.

`Counter` is a mutable class that you have created, whereas `number` is an integer (immutable).

As described in the other answers and comments, the immutable integer is overriden but since it is a local variable you cannot see these changes outside the function except if you return the value of `num` from `increment`.

Alternatively, you could make `number` a class variable of `Counter`. Hereby, you could track how many times any instance of `Counter` has ever increased the count:

```
class Counter:
    number_increases = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def increase(self):
        self.count += 1
        Counter.number_increases += 1


c1 = Counter()
c2 = Counter()

for i in range(10):
    c1.increase()

print(f"counters are {c1.count} and {c2.count}; " +
      f"number of times is {Counter.number_increases}")

for i in range(20):
    c2.increase()

print(f"counters are {c1.count} and {c2.count}; " +
      f"number of times is {Counter.number_increases}")
```

Output:

```
counters are 10 and 0; number of times is 10
counters are 10 and 20; number of times is 30
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because whenever you pass an argument to a function in python, you are using a copy of that argument, so writing `n += 1` will have no effect on the actual variable n outside of the function. You can try writing:

```
def increment(c, num):
    c.count += 1
    return num+1
```

and in the `for` loop you can do like this:

```
for i in range(100): # range(0, 100) is the same as range(100)
                     # because 0 is the default value for start
    number = increment(counter, number)
```

That should work.